# CROSS APPLY in MERGE - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, alias

I need to call function in the marge that return number.

And I want to ask about this number in the NOT MATCHED:

```
MERGE INTO Table AS m
USING (SELECT DISTINCT edb.*, md.F3, mb.F2 as , xp.idDetails
       FROM Table2 edb 
       JOIN Table4 mb ON md.F3 = mb.Id
       CROSS APPLY dbo.Func(edb.E1, edb.E2, edb.E3, edb.E4, edb.E5, edb.E6) xp(idDetails)
       WHERE xp.idDetails = md.Id
         AND edb.P1= 1000) edbTable ON m.R1 = edbTable.F2 AND m.R2 = 2

WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE 
        SET 
        .
        .
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND edbTable.idDetails IS NOT NULL THEN
    INSERT 
        .
        .
```

I try this code, but it failed:

> Table-valued function 'Func' cannot have a column alias.

Comment: Why do you have a comma in the from clause?

Comment: `and` is missing in `when not MATCHED edbTable.idDetails is not null then`

Comment: What does the function return? A table obviously, but what columns?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
USING (select distinct edb.*, md.F3, mb.F2
       from Table3 md join
            Table4 mb
            on md.F3 = mb.Id cross apply
            (select edb.*, xp.idDetails
             from table2 edb cross apply
                  dbo.Func(edb.E1, edb.E2, edb.E3, edb.E4, edb.E5, edb.E6) xp(idDetails)
             where xp.idDetails = md.Id and
                   edb.P1 = 1000
            ) edb
      )
```